# On-topic to find new stocks in certain business area?

Tags: support, specific-question

Is it on-topic if I ask for help finding publicly traded companies whose stock one can invest in, given that these companies are in a certain business area? I want to invest in AI companies, preferably early stages, but I know none such publicly traded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking for a specific stock recommendation would definitely be off-topic - there's a specific off-topic close reason for that:

> Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic
>   because they [tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Instead, describe your
>   situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

They also tend to attract spam or answers that are very hard to work out whether they are spam or not.

If you want to ask a general question about how to find those companies, that's probably ok in principle, though I worry a bit that it'll still attract spam or potential spam.